# DBCP 1.3 Validation Query Degrading Performance

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

I am working on a Spring-Batch where I am using an embedded DataSource (Apache Commons DBCP 1.3), JDBC3 db2jcc.jar for BD2 database and JDK1.5. I know DBCP2.x is already released but because of existing system (JDK 1.5) I cannot upgrade right now.

**DB Configurations:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="****"/>
    <property name="username" value="***"/>
    <property name="password" value="****"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="30000"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="5000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I noticed If I use **validationQuery** property along with **testOnBorrow**, **testOnReturn** and **testWhileIdle** to ture, the process taking 3 times higher time to complete.

While analyzing this I found there is a property "**validationInterval**" in tomcat JDBC connection pool.

**My question:**

1) Is there any way I can set a validationInterval in DBCP1.3 so that it would not validate the connection all the time but after a specified time period

2) If I don't use validationQuery is there any issue I may face?

3) If no validationQuery provided how DBCP1.3 will validate the connection?

**[EDIT]:**

Here is the test result after following Nitin suggestions:

**Run 1 with Previous Configurations:** 
Total Time taken - **74 Secs**

**Run 2 Configurations:** set testOnBorrow=true, testOnReturn=false, testWhileIdle=false

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="****"/>
    <property name="username" value="***"/>
    <property name="password" value="****"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Total time taken **47 secs**

However tweaking "**timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis**" not much changes in processing time but I have decided to set this to 30 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. Try

testOnBorrow=true

testOnReturn=false

testWhileIdle=false

2)

you may get stale(broken) connection for escaping validation. however, you may 'tweak' timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis ...that thread executes every 5 seconds to evict idle connection

3)

connection cannot be validated without validationQuery in DBCP 1.3

Comment: Thanks Nitin, the first option helps me to improve the performance 30%. I have edited my question and added test result. Can you please check my datasource configurations and let me know if any changes required.

Comment: You may try : Remove: maxIdle=10     Add: minIdle=1  Also for 'busy' system, 30 minutes for timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis is long, about minute (60000) seems ok

Comment: Thanks Nitin, I made the changes based on your suggestions and its woking fine. Appreciate for your help.